# SQL Append select result to temp table or table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I im trying to append results from select inside cursor to a temp table or temp variable. Please advice me how to do it in better way. My code works but insert function has a mistake which I cant determine. Also I need to use UNIOn to add a row under table which contains count for each numerical column under select result. My sample code is below, and my tables code is also under:

```
DECLARE @cnt INTEGER
SET @cnt=1


DECLARE @Ids INTEGER

CREATE TABLE #output_tab 
(
"Num" INTEGER,
"Name" VARCHAR(4),
"P1" INTEGER,
"P2" INTEGER,
"P3" INTEGER,
"P4" INTEGER,
"D1" INTEGER,
"D2" INTEGER,
"D3" INTEGER,
"D4" INTEGER
) 


DECLARE build_table CURSOR
    FOR 
        select distinct Id from #tab1;

OPEN build_table
FETCH NEXT FROM build_table INTO 
    @Ids;
        
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #output_tab (
        SELECT @cnt, e.Name, f.P1, f.P2, f.P3,f.P4, l.D1 , l.D2, l.D3, l.D4
        FROM #tab1 e
        LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT f.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.Id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS seqnum1
                FROM #tab2 f
        ) f ON f.Id = e.Id
        LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT l.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.Id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS seqnum2
                FROM #tab3 l
        ) l ON l.Id = e.Id AND (f.seqnum1 = l.seqnum2 OR f.seqnum1 IS NULL)
        where e.Id=@Ids);
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
        FETCH NEXT FROM build_table INTO 
            @Ids;
    END;

CLOSE build_table;

DEALLOCATE build_table;     
                  
select * from #output_tab 

drop table #output_tab
```

My tables code

```
CREATE TABLE #tab1 (
                    "Id" INTEGER,
                    "Name" VARCHAR(7),
                    "Status" VARCHAR(8)
                  );
                  
                  INSERT INTO #tab1
                    ("Id", "Name", "Status")
                  VALUES
                    ('101', 'Samsung', 'Enabled'),
                    ('102', 'Huawei', 'Disabled'),
                    ('103', 'Nokia', 'Enabled'),
                    ('104', 'Sony', 'Enabled');
                  
                  CREATE TABLE #tab2 (
                    "Id" INTEGER,
                    "P1" decimal(18,9),
                    "P2" INTEGER,
                    "P3" decimal(18,9),
                    "P4" decimal(18,9)
                  );
                  
                  INSERT INTO #tab2
                    ("Id", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4")
                  VALUES
                    ('101', '2', '5', '45', '56'),
                    ('101', '14', '3', '78', '7'),
                    ('101', '33', '2', '32', '34'),
                    ('102', '52', '1', '14', '61'),
                    ('102', '71', '0', '60', '88'),
                    ('103', '87.2', '2', '35.6', '84.6'),
                    ('103', '104.8', '67', '32.2', '96.4'),
                    ('103', '122.4', '3', '28.8', '108.2'),
                    ('103', '140', '5', '25.4', '120'),
                    ('104', '157.6', '7', '22', '131.8');
                  
                  CREATE TABLE #tab3 (
                    "Id" INTEGER,
                    "D1" INTEGER,
                    "D2" INTEGER,
                    "D3" INTEGER,
                    "D4" INTEGER
                  );
                  
                  INSERT INTO #tab3
                    ("Id", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4")
                  VALUES
                    ('101', '33', '2', '32', '34'),
                    ('102', '52', '1', '14', '61'),
                    ('102', '71', '0', '60', '88'),
                    ('102', '90', '32', '106', '115'),
                    ('102', '109', '14', '32', '34'),
                    ('103', '52', '1', '32', '34'),
                    ('103', '71', '0', '14', '61'),
                    ('104', '90', '32', '60', '88'),
                    ('104', '109', '14', '106', '115');
                    
                CREATE TABLE #tab4 (
                    "Id" INTEGER,
                    "E1" INTEGER,
                    "E2" INTEGER,
                    "E3" INTEGER,
                    "E4" INTEGER
                  );
                  
                  INSERT INTO #tab4
                    ("Id", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4")
                  VALUES
                    ('101', '43', '22', '87', '90'),
                    ('101', '62', '29', '23', '34'),
                    ('101', '79', '21', '76', '43'),
                    ('101', '92', '200', '11', '0'),
                    ('102', '54', '779', '12', '484'),
                    ('103', '592', '41', '326', '334'),
                    ('103', '731', '10', '134', '651'),
                    ('104', '920', '332', '650', '868'),
                    ('104', '16', '143', '1026', '1145');
```

Im using cursor here cuse I need to achive such a view of the output result. Assuming that blanks are filled with Null
[Image of my desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8bc2.png)

Comment: The parenthesis after the destination table shoiuld be a list of the target columns; you have `INSERT INTO #output_tab ( {Select statement})`. It should be `INSERT INTO #output_tab ({Column List}) SELECT ...`.

Comment: Goodness me, why is that a cursor? That could all be a single insert statement with `@Cnt` being replaced by `dense_rank() over (order by e.Id) as Num`.

Comment: Its because I need to create output in special form. And I need to add a tow with count total for each column. It would be great if give me better variant cause im also not sure that cursor is the only way to realize this task

Comment: Ive added image of my desired output whats why I use cursor. Cause I need also to add a row with totals under every company

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` This is logical nonsense. Beware of this approach. The values generated are not deterministic and can vary over time.

Comment: You need something deterministic to join on as stated above, Also the columns should be numeric datatype not strings as you seemingly want to aggregate them. But anyway you can bin the cursor and use `ROLLUP` or `GROUPING SETS` to get sub totals and grand totals

Comment: one last comment - your goal is effectively to produce a "pretty" report. Suppression of repeating values, subtotal and total rows, etc. These are all very easy to do with a reporting tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T-SQL is not really the place to do this kind of manipulation for display purposes. You should use your presentation layer to do this.

Be that as it may, you can use the following

- `ROW_NUMBER` to join the three tables together.
- `tab2` and `tab3` need a `FULL JOIN` betweeen them, then `LEFT JOIN that back to` tab1`.
- `LAG` and `NULLIF` to null out `Id` of rows of the same group
- `GROUPING SETS` to generate rollup rows.

```sql
SELECT
  Id     = NULLIF(t1.Id    , LAG(t1.Id    ) OVER (ORDER BY t1.Id)),
  Name   = CASE WHEN GROUPING(t2.P1) = 1
                THEN 'Total'
                ELSE NULLIF(t1.Name, LAG(t1.Name) OVER (ORDER BY t1.Id))
           END,
  P1 = SUM(t2.P1),
  P2 = SUM(t2.P2),
  P3 = SUM(t2.P3),
  P4 = SUM(t2.P4),
  D1 = SUM(t3.D1),
  D2 = SUM(t3.D2),
  D3 = SUM(t3.D3),
  D4 = SUM(t3.D4)
FROM #tab1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.Id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM #tab2 t2
    ) t2
    FULL JOIN (
        SELECT *,
          rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t3.Id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM #tab3 t3
      ) t3 ON t3.Id = t2.Id
           AND t3.rn = t2.rn
  ON ISNULL(t2.Id, t3.Id) = t1.Id
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
 (
  t1.Id, t1.Name, t2.P1, t2.P2, t2.P3, t2.P4, t3.D1, t3.D2, t3.D3, t3.D4
 ),
 (
  t1.Id, t1.Name
 ) 
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=344b6e1917c7b2a12eeb5fabade77b05)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! yes its just what I need. It but seems Sony disappered somethere, and Huawei has 4 raws in tab3 but only 2 showed

Comment: The fiddle has a `...` button at the bottom of the table

Comment: Oops sorry. But Huawei still has just 2 rows instead of 4 I think it because tab2 has 2 rows for huawei but how they connected. Ive noticed this mistake in my code also there should be 4 rows of D and 2 rows of P filled and 2 rows of P filled with Null

Comment: Fixed that now.

Comment: Thanx a lot again. Works amazing now. Im trying to play with ordering cause i dont know yet why  it shows results from beggining to end for Samsung and Nokia and from end to beggining for Huawei and Sony

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f021ffd6b379abb81f56af6441f7d8a0 note the `ORDER BY` on both the outer query and in the `LAG`

Comment: Im already nearly understood the mechanism! Im trying now to add one more tab to understand how joins works. But it seems I cant use full join for joining one more tab? [added  tab4 ](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ff825cb94c975c3bf55acde59558caa6)

Comment: When you use multiple `FULL JOIN`s each table needs to use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` on *all* previous tables in order to join correctly. And you want to `LEFT JOIN` that final result back to `t1` so the `ON` of that first join has to go after all the others. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=015726e5ce091345bb9f25198de8dd71

Comment: oops it seems now results connected to each other mean the number of displayed raws from tab3 depends on number of rows of tab2 and tab4 depends on tab2 a guess. For example I've added more rows to tab4 for Sony but it shows only 2 may be because tab3 for sony has 2 rows only, I've also removed all raws for Samsung except one from tab2 and it show now just one row but tab4 has 4 rows for samsung. (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f8a8a269f3f41f2f3c6c25e160e9f31)

Comment: Need to add `t4.Id` as part of the final join condition https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f0da245bfc417f8d5bb2387f520fd644

Comment: Hi. but Is it possible to use Rollup instead of of grouping sets or they are not the same? ive discovered that groping sets has 32 columns limitation limitation :(

Comment: `ROLLUP` will have the same limitation, it is essentially shorthand for `GROUPING SETS`. I think with that many columns you should consider a different tool, such as PivotTables or Excel